# jQuery children function gives no result

Tags: jquery, html

What I want to reach, is to generate dynamically text boxes with jQuery, so, the jQuery code:

```
var num = $('.question-container-1').length;
var newNum = new Number(num + 1); 

var newElem = $('#question-container-' + num).clone().attr('id', 'question-container-' + newNum);            
newElem.children('input[type=text]').val('');

$('#question-container-' + num).after(newElem);
```

and the html code:

```
<fieldset id="question-container-1" class="question-container-1">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">Întrebare</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="question" id="question-box" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <a href="#" id="add-question-1" class="add-question-1">Adaugă întrebare</a>
            <a href="#" id="delete-question-1" class="delete-question-1" style="margin-left: 20px;">Șterge întrebare</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

After all, everything works perfectly, except for one thing, they are clones from the last textfield, but I don't want to copy the value of it as well, how you can see I tried with children function to find textfield, but it does not erase the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.children()` works only one descendant level down. You want `.find()` instead, which goes all the way down to the last, farthest descendant. :D

Comment: Million dollar answer. :). Thanks :D